# C# For Loop Confusion

Tags: c#

Why does "num" turn into 0 at some time?

```
int num = 16;
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num *= i);
}
```

Comment: What values does `num` take on before it becomes 0?

Comment: Just look at each operation, line by line.  Perform the operation yourself by hand, and see why it ends up being what it ends up being.

Comment: @DavidG - This is a proper answer :) was about to post it myself. Worth that you post it :)

Comment: Change num *= i to just num * i

Comment: @ScottHunter -1073741824

Comment: @john: And the product of a sequence of positive value producing a negative result didn't bother you?

Comment: I understand that it overflows lol... But doesn't it have to stop at some value different than 0?? or is it just a coincidence for exactly this number?

Comment: @john Like I said.  Perform the operation by hand.  Multiply that value by the current value of `i`, and see what happens.

Comment: @ScottHunter ok but why does it overflow since -1073741824*2=-2 147 483 648 (the min value of an integer), why does it overflow at this particular moment? I mean shouldn't it keep it in it ? and overflow on the next iteration?

Comment: @ScottHunter never mind... totally forgot i am multiplying by 32 now

Comment: @john, don't get hung up on the sign, that's just the left most bit being set to 1.  Try it with `uint` and think about the values and when it becomes 0 and that should make more sense.

Comment: Compile with the checked compiler switch and see for yourself

Answer (score 4):

At your 31st iteration, `num` will be `-1073741824` due to overflowing which you say you already understand.

In the next (32nd) iteration you multiply `num` by `32` which is `b100000` as binary. This multiplication is the same as shifting the value 5 bits to the left.

`-1073741824` is `0xC0000000`, and if you shift that 5 bits to the left, your **32bit** value ends up being `0x00000000` => zero.

Comment: Nice way to tie up all of the pieces of this question!

Answer (score 2):

Each time `i` is a multiple of 2, multiplying `n` by it gives `n` that many more `0` bits on the end.  Eventually, it has enough to fill the variable, making it 0.

Comment: It's more than just the powers of 2 that "left shift", see my answer. (it just has to be an even number)

Comment: @DavidG: Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you multiply by an even number, you add one or more binary zeros to the right side of the number, but you will *never* remove one. Eventually you hit a point where all of the digits are zero.

This is the sequence you get, note that the right side only ever gets a longer sequence of zero digits:

```
01:                              10000  <= 4 zeros
02:                             100000  <= 5 zeros
03:                            1100000  <= 5 zeros
04:                          110000000  <= 7 zeros
05:                        11110000000  <= 7 zeros
06:                     10110100000000  <= 8 zeros
07:                  10011101100000000  <= 8 zeros
08:               10011101100000000000  <= 11 zeros
09:            10110001001100000000000  <= 11 zeros
10:         11011101011111000000000000  <= 12 zeros
11:     100110000100010101000000000000  <= 12 zeros
12:   11001000110011111100000000000000  <= 14 zeros
13:     110010100011001100000000000000  <= 14 zeros
14:   11000011101100101000000000000000  <= 15 zeros
15:    1110111011101011000000000000000  <= 15 zeros
16:    1110111010110000000000000000000  <= 19 zeros
17:   11101100110110000000000000000000  <= 19 zeros
18:   10100111001100000000000000000000  <= 20 zeros
19:    1101000100100000000000000000000  <= 20 zeros
20:     101011010000000000000000000000  <= 22 zeros
21:   10001100010000000000000000000000  <= 22 zeros
22:       1101100000000000000000000000  <= 23 zeros
23:     110110100000000000000000000000  <= 23 zeros
24:      11100000000000000000000000000  <= 26 zeros
25:   10111100000000000000000000000000  <= 26 zeros
26:      11000000000000000000000000000  <= 27 zeros
27:   10001000000000000000000000000000  <= 27 zeros
28:   11100000000000000000000000000000  <= 29 zeros
29:    1100000000000000000000000000000  <= 29 zeros
30:    1000000000000000000000000000000  <= 30 zeros
31:   11000000000000000000000000000000  <= 30 zeros
```

Comment: `num` is initially 16 (0x10 or b10000).

Comment: Why'd you start with 1101 (11 decimal)?

Comment: @ScottHunter My testing code.... started with 11 as the initial value... fixed! Was just trying to show that it doesn't matter what number you start with